# Desktop Animated Application in Java

Tags: java, applet, javafx, java-2d, java-3d

I want to create java Desktop Application (J2SE). In this application lot of **animation** is required.Please Recommend me which API is suitable for development.

Major focus on:

- Animation
- Reliability
- Scalability; and
- Maintenance etc.

**i.e JavaFx, Java 2D, Java 3D or Applets etc**

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

libgdx or Trident, both are well documented.

Trident getting started is here : http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2009/02/14/introducing-trident-animation-library-for-java-applications.html